# Firestore - How to get document ID after fetching document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my database from Firestore, each User has a sub-collection called Apps. I would like to create sub-URLs with the ID of each app. But I have no idea how to get the document ID of my Apps sub-collection.
Maybe I have to use an `onSnapshot()` method, but I'm not sure how to use it in my situation.

Thanks for your help.

```js
function AppList() {
  const [apps, setApps] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      if (user != null) {
        var uid = user.uid;
        const data = await db
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(uid)
          .collection("Apps")
          .get();
        setApps(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Row gutter={{ xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }}>
      {apps.map(app => (
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={100}>
          <Card
            style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 16 }}
            actions={[
              <Button type="default" size="middle">
                <Link to={}>
                  <EditOutlined />
                  <span> Edit the app </span>
                </Link>
              </Button>
            ]}
          >
            <Meta title={app.appName} description={app.description} />
          </Card>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data.docs` is an array of [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) objects.  Each will have an [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id) property with the ID of the document.  If you want to add it to your state, try something like this:

```
setApps(data.docs.map(doc => { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()));
```

This should create a property `id` on each mapped object, along with the data from the other fields using the JavaScript spread operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code doesn't work. I tried the following console.log and it works: 
`data.docs.map(doc => console.log(doc.id, doc.data()))`

But how can I add it to my state? Because the following code doesn't work: 
`setApps(data.docs.map(doc => doc.id, doc.data()))`

Comment: Adding it to your state sounds like a whole different problem than just getting the ID.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Doug Stevenson is correct as idea or pseudocode. The working code is as follows (taken from my working app, so some names are changed, but that is not a challenge to apply them correctly):

```
const allComments = value
        ? value.docs.map(doc => {
              return { firebaseID: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
          })
        : null;
```